# ldconfig not finding libprotobuf.so

Tags: linux, compiling

I am attempting to install the [protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) library on a Redhat system (Amazon EC2's Linux build). I ran `configure`, `make`, and `make install` without a problem, and the `.so` libraries were copied over to `/usr/local/lib`. Since Redhat doesn't include the `/usr/local/lib` directory in `/etc/ld.so.conf`, I added it, and then ran `ldconfig` to update the linkages.

My problem is that, for whatever reason, `ldconfig` isn't picking up `libprotobuf.so`, even though it is in the `/usr/local/lib` directory.

Here is the output of `ls -l /usr/local/lib`:

```
total 61336
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 17654940 Mar 26 02:39 libprotobuf.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      994 Mar 26 02:39 libprotobuf.la
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1948106 Mar 26 02:39 libprotobuf-lite.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     1029 Mar 26 02:39 libprotobuf-lite.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       25 Mar 26 02:39 libprotobuf-lite.so -> libprotobuf-lite.so.7.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       25 Mar 26 02:39 libprotobuf-lite.so.7 -> libprotobuf-lite.so.7.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   893083 Mar 26 02:39 libprotobuf-lite.so.7.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       20 Mar 26 02:39 libprotobuf.so -> libprotobuf.so.7.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       20 Mar 26 02:39 libprotobuf.so.7 -> libprotobuf.so.7.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  7326093 Mar 26 02:39 libprotobuf.so.7.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 25883264 Mar 26 02:39 libprotoc.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     1010 Mar 26 02:39 libprotoc.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       18 Mar 26 02:39 libprotoc.so -> libprotoc.so.7.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       18 Mar 26 02:39 libprotoc.so.7 -> libprotoc.so.7.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  9071740 Mar 26 02:39 libprotoc.so.7.0.0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Mar 26 02:39 pkgconfig
```

Here is the output of `ldconfig -v | grep protobuf`:

```
libprotobuf.so.7 -> libprotobuf.so.7.0.0
libprotobuf-lite.so.7 -> libprotobuf-lite.so.7.0.0
```

What do I have to do to get `libprotobuf` recognized by the linker?

**Edit**:
When I try to link the library directly, I get this error:

```
ldconfig: Ignored file /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so since it is not a regular file.
```

I tried copying `libprotobuf.so.7.0.0` over `libprotobuf.so` so that it is no longer a symlink, which fixed the error, but my linker still can't find `libprotobuf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ld.so.conf` is only used by the runtime dynamic linker. `ld` doesn't us that at all - you need to pass `/usr/local/lib` as a linker search directory (either directly to `ld` if you're calling it directly, or via your compiler).

For `ld`, GCC (or clang, and possibly quite a few other compilers), you do that with the `-L` flag.

Comment: You're right; I was barking up the wrong tree. My problem was as trivial as it gets -- I was passing `-Llibprotobuf` to GCC instead of `-Lprotobuf`. Thanks!